# Declaring fixed size string properties in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How do I declare a fixed size string property in Delphi?

This is what I want to do, but I receive an error:

```
TMyObject = class(TObject)
private
  FName : string[20];
public
  property Name : string[20] read FName write FName;     //<-- error
end;
```

The compiler error reads: 'INDEX, READ, or WRITE clause expected, but '[' found'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this

```
type
Str20=string[20];

TMyObject = class(TObject)
private
  FName : Str20;
public
  property Name : Str20 read FName write FName;     //<-- error
end;
```